# Different description about enum

Tags: c, enums

I try to write a chess engine but the following code is diffucult to understand.I especially didnt understand the commas after the equality expression.

```
enum {
    A1 = 21, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, H1,
    A2 = 31, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, H2,
    A3 = 41, B3, C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, H3,
    A4 = 51, B4, C4, D4, E4, F4, G4, H4,
    A5 = 61, B5, C5, D5, E5, F5, G5, H5,
    A6 = 71, B6, C6, D6, E6, F6, G6, H6,
    A7 = 81, B7, C7, D7, E7, F7, G7, H7,
    A8 = 91, B8, C8, D8, E8, F8, G8, H8, NO_SQ, OFFBOARD
  };
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: There is no "equality expression" in the code. In fact, the only expressions in this code are integer literals.

Comment: I didnt undertand what this code makes

Comment: He's probably asking why we put value to `A1` and not `B1`. The answer would be that following elements in enum take the previous one's value + 1. So, `B1 = 22`, `H8 = 98`, `NO_SQ = 99`. If they didn't give value to `A2`, it would take `H1+1`, which is 29, not 31.

Comment: I don't get why this question got -1. Upvoted to fix this. It's pretty clear what this guy is asking. I think overall we're rushing into downvoting and flaming around here

Comment: It looks like this setup is a kind of lazy hack to create shortcuts for human-readable numbers "row,column" on a board with padding, so actual board positions are `10` up to `109`. Padding is useful for certain chess algorithms because it allows you to not treat the board boundary as a special case; instead you just place unpassable pieces on the padding fields.

Comment: I concur with the downvote,  this forum is for questions about code that needs debugging,, not about teaching the C language

Comment: you wrote the code, therefore you should understand what you wrote.  Otherwise why did you write it?

Comment: Obviously, he didn't write the code. Help if you want or don't, but how does this knitpickicking help? This question can definitely help people to write better code...

Answer (score 1):

Enums are a shorthand for enumeration. If you have a sequence of definitions whom values succeed each other you can use enums to automatically increment values instead of manually defining each one.
The = sign dictates at which number to begin the enumeration, and it can be set multiple times in the same enum, each restarting the enumeration at the specified number.

Please see comments in the code below to further explain this.

```
enum {
    /* A1=21 implies B1=22, C1=23,... */
    A1 = 21, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, H1,
    /* A2=31 restarts the previous enumeration at 31, so B2=32, C2=33,... */
    A2 = 31, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, H2,
    /* And so on, A3=41,B3=42,C3=43... */
    A3 = 41, B3, C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, H3,
    A4 = 51, B4, C4, D4, E4, F4, G4, H4,
    A5 = 61, B5, C5, D5, E5, F5, G5, H5,
    A6 = 71, B6, C6, D6, E6, F6, G6, H6,
    A7 = 81, B7, C7, D7, E7, F7, G7, H7,
    A8 = 91, B8, C8, D8, E8, F8, G8, H8, NO_SQ, OFFBOARD
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerated Types allow us to create our own symbolic names for a list of related ideas. The key word for an enumerated type is enum. For example, we could create an enumerated type for true and false

```
enum Security_Levels 
    { 
      black_ops, 
      top_secret, 
      secret, 
      non_secret 
    };
```

this is the way you can initilaize enum in C